# algorithm for ant movement in 2 row table

Tags: algorithm, graph

Problem:

There is a table with below constraints:

```
   a) it has 2 row only.
   b) and n col. so basically its 2xN table but N is a power  of two.
   c) its short ends are joint together you can move from last element of the row to the first element of row if first element is not visited.
```

Now you are given 2 initial position i1 and i2 for ants and final destination f1 and f2. Now ant have to reach f1 and f2, but either of the ant can reach either of point . example if i1 reach f2 and i2 have to reach f1.
     Allowed moves:-

```
1) Ant can move horizontally and vertically only no diagonal movement.
2) each cell can be visited at most by one ant and all the cell must be visited in the end.
```

Output:- path traced by two ants if all the cell are marked visited else -1. Need complexity for the algorithm also.

Comment: By "visited", do you mean that once an ant has been in a certain cell then no other ants can get to that cell? Or do you mean that there is space for only one ant at any time?

Comment: once any ant visited a cell then any other ant cannot visit it.

Comment: Dynamic programming -> linear time (works on all graph families with bounded treewidth).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat... can you please elaborate  your hint....

Comment: @YSBhai Does the problem say you should reduce it to a flow problem? You had the ford-fulkerson tag originally.

Comment: @Rockonrockout.... Some one gave me the same  hint.. i am not able to reailze  the problem as max flow problem

Answer (score 0):

Max flow can be used to compute two disjoint paths, but it is not possible to express the constraint of visiting all squares in a generic fashion (it's possible that there's a one-off trick). **This dynamic programming solution isn't the slickest**, but the ideas behind it can be applied to many similar problems.

The first step is to decompose the instance recursively, bottoming out with little pieces. (The constraints on these pieces will become apparent shortly.) For this problem, the root piece is the whole 2-by-n array. The two child pieces of the root are 2-by-n/2 arrays. The four children of those pieces are 2-by-n/4 arrays. We bottom out with 2-by-1 arrays.

Now, consider what a solution looks like from the point of view of a piece.

```
  +---+-- ... --+---+
A | B |         | C | D
  +---+-- ... --+---+
E | F |         | G | H
  +---+-- ... --+---+
```

Squares `B, C, F, G` are inside the piece. Squares `A, E` are the left boundary. Squares `D, H` are the right boundary. If an ant enters this piece, it does so from one of the four boundary squares (or its initial position, if that's inside the piece). Similarly, if an ant leaves this piece, it does so to one of the four boundary squares (or its final position, if that's inside the piece). Since each square can be visited at most once, there is a small number of possible permutations for the comings and goings of both ants:

```
 Ant 1: enters A->B, leaves C->D
 Ant 2: enters E->F, leaves G->H

 Ant 1: enters A->B, leaves G->H
 Ant 2: does not enter

 Ant 1: enters A->B, leaves C->D, enters H->G, leaves F->E
 Ant 2: does not enter

 Ant 1: enters A->B, leaves F->E, enters H->G, leaves C->D
 Ant 2: does not enter

 ...
```

The key fact is that what the ants do strictly outside of this piece has no bearing on what happens strictly inside. For each piece in the recursive decomposition, we can compute the set of comings and goings that are consistent with all squares in the piece being covered. For the 2-by-1 arrays, this can be accomplished with brute force.

```
  +---+
A | B | C
  +---+
D | E | F
  +---+
```

In general, neither ant starts or ends inside this piece. Then the some of the possibilities are

```
Ant 1: A->B, B->E, E->F; Ant 2: none
Ant 1: A->B, B->C, F->E, E->D; Ant 2: none
Ant 1: A->B, B->C; Ant 2: D->E; E->F
Ant 1: A->B, B->C, D->E, E->F; Ant 2: none .
```

Now, suppose we have computed the sets (DP tables hereafter) for two adjacent pieces that are the children of one parent piece.

```
                   1|2
  +---+-- ... --+---+---+-- ... --+---+
A | B |         | C | D |         | E | F
  +---+-- ... --+---+---+-- ... --+---+
G | H |         | I | J |         | K | L
  +---+-- ... --+---+---+-- ... --+---+
                   1|2
```

Piece `1` is to the left of the dividing line. Piece `2` is to the right of the dividing line. Once again, there is a small number of possibilities for traffic on the named squares. The DP table for the parent piece is indexed by the traffic at `A, B, E, F, G, H, K, L`. For each entry, we try all possibilities for the traffic at `C, D, I, J`, using the children's DP tables to determine whether the combined comings and goings are feasible.